# Pandas create dictionary with merge cells

Tags: python, pandas

I have the excels file with merged cells on column A and 2 values on column B and C like on this image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnPsf.png (sorry I'm not allowed to upload images yet)
In case the image not working, I'm posting the example too:

```
A       B        C
        B1       C1 
A       B2       C2
        B3       C3
```

The results I want is {A:[(B1,C1),(B2,C2),(B3,C3)]}, is there any way to do this? Thank you very much

EDIT 1: this is the output of print(df.info())

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   A       0 non-null      float64
 1   B1      2 non-null      object
 2   C1      2 non-null      object
dtypes: float64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 176.0+ bytes
None
```

EDIT 2: I followed answer of @jezrael and its worked

Comment: What is `print (df.info())` after created DataFrame?

Comment: @jezrael its like the one I updated on EDIT 1

Comment: There are columns `B1,C1` ? Not `B,C` ?

Comment: Is possible create `print (df.head().to_dict())` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First forward filling missing values and then create nested lists, `groupby` is used for working if multiple categories in column `A`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 'A', 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan}, 
                   'B': {0: 'B1', 1: 'B2', 2: 'B3'},
                   'C': {0: 'C1', 1: 'C2', 2: 'C3'}})

df['A'] = df['A'].ffill()

d = df.groupby('A')[['B','C']].apply(lambda x: [tuple(y) for y in x.to_numpy()]).to_dict()
print (d)
{'A': [('B1', 'C1'), ('B2', 'C2'), ('B3', 'C3')]}
```

Comment: thank you but its only return the first row, not the second and third row >{'A': (array(['B1', 'C1'], dtype=object),)}

Comment: @Rotomegax Is possible create `print (df.head().to_dict())` ?

Comment: yes, its returned like this {'A': {0: 'A', 1: nan, 2: nan}, 'B': {0: 'B1', 1: 'B2', 2: 'B3'}, 'C': {0: 'C1', 1: 'C2', 2: 'C3'}}

Comment: @Rotomegax - Answer was edited.